# Showing Toolbar in Only Specific Views in Lotus Notes 8.5

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I was wondering if it was possible to only show a toolbar in Lotus notes for certain windows. For example, I only want my toolbar to show when the user opens the mail window, and maybe I want a different toolbar to show when he opens the Calendar window.

I am developing my plugin in Eclipse using the Expeditor Framework and stuff like that. Let me know if you need any more information, and I will do my best to provide it ASAP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but there are 2 toolbars effectively in Notes: 1) is the main ribbon (smartIcons) under the main menu and 2) the Action Bar defined for each view.

1. It may be possible to change the smarticon ribbon toolbar with @commands (guessing here) or maybe some API call (external c-based call?) but unlikley to be easy/possible.
2. As for the Action buttons, you can define (mostly) what you want on the Action Bar. The action bar buttons can be shown/hidden under program control (hide-whens) and are defined per view (or shared amongst similar views) as needed. However, if you want to change the default mail/calendar actions of the default mail template, there are additional reasons not to or consequences of changing the standard mail design/template which might incur a lot of additional work to support. It is possble though if really needed/justified.

Note: As you probably know, usually, both toolbars show by default - its not either/or.

Comment: Hmm, this does help a little bit. If you could give me specific API calls that would be SO sage. Thanks anyways.